# Software to store hierarchal data

Tags: php, linux, hierarchy

I'm looking for [free] server software to store hierarchal data efficiently. My key challenge is that an object or group of objects almost always has 2 "parents" and one or both parents can have different connections with other parents, and those descendants must remain distinct from the common parent's other descendants.

Example:

```
A and B
    C
    D
    E and F
        G
        H
    E and I
        J
        K
L and M
    ...
```

I guess the gotcha will probably be that I'd strongly prefer to use this with PHP, but I'm open to learning a new language, as this is a personal project without any deadline. (I'm using a Linux server; I'm not willing to change that)

Edit:
To clarify my example - C, D and E are all *direct* descendants of both A and B, F and I are descendants of something else, possibly the same thing, possibly not, G and K are both direct descendants of both E and F, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can use [Graphviz dot](http://www.graphviz.org/) to model/graph relationships.  Here's the updated content of the .dot file, more like your clarification:

```
digraph G {
    compound = true // allow edges between clusters
    subgraph cluster_ab {
        rank = same;
        A -> B -> A
    }
    A -> C [ltail=cluster_ab]
    A -> D [ltail=cluster_ab]
    A -> E [ltail=cluster_ab]
    subgraph cluster_ef {
        rank = same;
        E -> F -> E
    }
    E -> G [ltail=cluster_ef]
    E -> H [ltail=cluster_ef]

    subgraph cluster_ei {
        E -> I -> E
    }
    I -> J [ltail=cluster_ei]
    I -> K [ltail=cluster_ei]
}
```

[sample dot output http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/6177/64094067.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/6177/64094067.png)

This one is a little different, because you can't create overlapping clusters (E->I and E->F).  But I think it's more like the way you've clarified, even though it isn't terribly apparent that E and I are siblings -- I also had to make sure to link from I to J,K, otherwise there was a warning and it looked a bit uglier.

There are [plenty of libraries that interface with Graphviz/dot](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php) that would let you generate these kinds of graphs dynamically, rather than by hand as I did.  Then if you've already got a library to store/retrieve directed graphs, you're pretty much there on storing hierarchical data.  As to whether it's *efficient*, as you mentioned in your question... depends on how much data you're storing, of course.

---

As @Kim points out in the comments, you can get a quite simplified graph by treating siblings as pairs, rather than individual nodes:

```
digraph G {
    "A,B" -> C
    "A,B" -> D
    "A,B" -> E
    "E,F" -> G
    "E,F" -> H

    "E,I" -> J
    "E,I" -> K
}
```

It's an obvious and elegant solution that I completely overlooked, although it remains a little ambiguous about sibling relationships when overlap occurs (E again).

[simpler graph http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/8969/so2b.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/8969/so2b.png)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer - not whatt I'm looking for for this project, but I'll definitely be able to use it. In my example, C, D and E are all *direct* descendants of both A and B (F and I are descendants of something else, possibly the same thing, not necessarily though). Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: I should say, rather, that this *may* not be what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you think of "A and B" as the pair (A,B), then you could model it as a graph whose nodes can be pairs. Then you could use any graph-library you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think should be easier to write your own php classes, wich will be much more suitable for your needs. Maybe something like this (pseudocode)

```
Class Item  
  [List of Item] Parents 
  [List of Item] Children
```

The challenge is to write the methods to manage /build up the complete structure. Persisting also the level nbr should help a lot in your case.
You already have [related questions in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hierarchical+database) about saving hierarchical structures into a database.